# how to access li text to create new list with javascript

Tags: javascript, list, function, append

I cannot get this function to work correctly. it only list the first word of foodlist (by default is food) and if i select more than one item from foodlist it does not create a new li for each selection. what am i doing wrong?

So far the best approach i have found is splitting the list string into an array and then appending the 0 index to the searchList ul. but it will only list the first item from the foodlist.

```js
function addToList(){
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;



  let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.';
    document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(li);

  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = 1;
    li.appendChild(checkbox);
};


function addToPantry () {
  for (i = 0; i<foodlist.length; i++){
    let name = foodlist[0];
    pantry.push(`${name}: [${amount}, [${unit}]]`)
  }


}

function addToSearch() {
  let list = document.getElementById("foodlist").innerText;
  let split = list.split(" ")

  if (list.checked = true){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent =split[0];
      document.getElementById("searchList").appendChild(li);
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
  <br><br>

<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
  <br><br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>
  <br><br>

<button  onclick ="addToList(), addToPantry()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>

<ul id="foodlist"></ul>

<button onclick="addToSearch()" type="button" id="toSearch" name="button">Add To Search </button>

  </div>
<h3>You are searching for recipes containing:</h3>

<ul id="searchList"></ul>
```

Comment: So you're saying that if I type in "food two three" I should get three `li`s? One with "food" (plus amount, etc.), another with "two" (plus amount, etc.), and another with "three"? Your code doesn't seem to make any attempt to make that happen. You're on the right track with `split`, perhaps show us what you tried and we can tell you where you went arong.

Comment: Update condition if (list.checked = true){ with if (list.checked == true){

Comment: with the === it wont work at all. if  zzz amount unit, and uuuuu amount unit are entered and selected, i want it to return zzz and uuuuu as separate list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the wrong comparison, which is an assignment, you need to take the elements of `foodlist` and check if one input is checked. Then update the list.

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.';
  document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(li);

  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.value = 1;
  li.appendChild(checkbox);
}

function addToPantry() {
  for (i = 0; i < foodlist.length; i++) {
    let name = foodlist[0];
    pantry.push(`${name}: [${amount}, [${unit}]]`)
  }
}

function addToSearch() {
  let list = document.getElementById("foodlist").getElementsByTagName('li'),
      i;
      
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].querySelector('input').checked) { //
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = list[i].innerText;
      document.getElementById("searchList").appendChild(li);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
<br><br>
<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button onclick="addToList(), addToPantry()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>
<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
<button onclick="addToSearch()" type="button" id="toSearch" name="button">Add To Search </button>
<h3>You are searching for recipes containing:</h3>
<ul id="searchList"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! how do i get it to only return the food name though? as is it returns: food amount unit, but all i want it to return is food

Comment: for getting clean string, i would store the foods in an array and take the index as `value` for the checkbox. then pick the value from the checkbox and from the array the food.

Answer (score -1):

You have `if (list.checked = true)`, that doesn't look like comparison to me - it always evaluates to true.

Comment: This is true, but it seems to be tangential to the OP's described problem. Worth just commenting, rather than answering. (Haresh already did so.)